# ValueError: Not enough values to unpack - renaming files

Tags: python

I followed the steps in this video to the letter and am getting an error that he was not getting: ValueError: Not enough values to unpack (Expected 4, got 1). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ve2pmm5JqmI

I've been able to produce an array like in the video with 4 values instead of 3.

my code is below, I get an error after that last line.

```
file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)

file_name = file_name.replace(' ', '-')
file_name = file_name.replace('---', '-')
file_name = file_name.replace('[', '')
file_name = file_name.replace(']', '')

f_hor, f_name, f_num, f_res = file_name.split('-')
```

If I do print(file_name) instead of the last line above, I get:

```
['firstvalue', 'secondvalue', 'thirdvalue', 'fourthvalue']
['firstvalue', 'secondvalue', 'thirdvalue', 'fourthvalue']
...
['firstvalue', 'secondvalue', 'thirdvalue', 'fourthvalue']
```

What am I doing wrong that he isn't doing in the video? If I try to instead do

```
 file_name = file_name.split('-')
 f_firstvalue = file_name[0]
 f_firstvalue = file_name[1]
 f_firstvalue = file_name[2]
 f_firstvalue = file_name[3]
```

I instead get "list index out of range". Please help :(

Comment: What is the value of `f`?

Comment: Do your filenames contain at least three instances of `-`? Could you give an example of a filename that you start with and what you would expect it to become?

Comment: I start with (useless information)-(show name)-(episode number)-(resolution). I've already stripped the file extension out and have it stored properly in a variable f_ext. So what's left is just the file name. As in the video, the goal is to do:

     new_name = '{}-{}{}'.format(f_num, file_title, file_ext)
     os.rename(fn, new_name)